# Url validation with regex for old php version

Tags: php, regex, function

> **Note**: I'm using an older PHP version so `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` is not available at this time.

After many many searches I am still unable to find the exact answer that can cover all URL structure possibilities but at the end I'm gonna use this way:

I'm using the following function

1) Function to get proper scheme

```
function convertUrl ($url){
    $pattern = '#^http[s]?://#i';
    if(preg_match($pattern, $url) == 1) { // this url has proper scheme
        return $url;
    } else {
        return 'http://' . $url;
    }
}
```

2) Conditional to check if it is a URL or not

```
if (preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i", $url)) {
  echo "URL is valid";
}else {
  echo "URL is invalid<br>";
}
```

Guess What!? It works so perfect for all of these possibilities:

```
$url = "google.com";
$url = "www.google.com";
$url = "http://google.com";
$url = "http://www.google.com";
$url = "https://google.com";
$url = "https://www.codgoogleekarate.com";
$url = "subdomain.google.com";
$url = "https://subdomain.google.com";
```

**But still have this edge case**

```
$url = "blahblahblahblah";
```

The function `convertUrl($url)` will convert this to `$url = "http://blahblahblahblah";`
then the regex will consider it as valid URL while it isn't!!

How can I edit it so that it won't pass a URL with this structure `http://blahblahblahblah`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (preg_match("/^(([\w]+:)?\/\/)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?$/", $url)) {
  echo "URL is valid";
}else {
  echo "URL is invalid<br>";
}
```

Comment: This is baloney. I can get the same results with `/\./`. It doesn't mean the url is valid.

Comment: @pguardiario test it with `convertUrl` function i've mention in my question, i've tested in almost all possibilities and it did the work perfect.

Comment: Right, but a stopped clock is also right sometimes. The fact that you're unable to tell the difference doesn't make this a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate *internet url's*, add a check for including a dot (.) character in your reg-ex.

`Note: http://blahblahblah is a valid url as is http://localhost`

Comment: Yes `http://localhost` is valid but since my website is online so why i do allow for `http://localhost` .. thanks for your answer and i do really need to edit the regex so it can check if there is `.` or not.